# How to call a custom tab from li tag in salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, html5

I have a list of names with li tags and custom salesforce tabs with the same names. how can make a tab active when i select respected name from the list.

```
    <apex:page>
      <li><a href="#">My Tabs</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">My First</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">My Second</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>

    <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="t1" id="tab_pannel">
     <apex:tab label="My First" name="t1" id="tabOne">
     ...
     </apex:tab>
     <apex:tab label="My Second" name="t2" id="tabtwo">
     ...
     </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
  </apex:page>
```

(ex:Here when i select My First the tab My First should be active....)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems the [apex:tabPanel](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_tabPanel.htm) component **does not have a client side API** to make tabs active **via JavaScript**. That said, I have two solutions to this, one client side, the other server side.

**Client Side Only**

This solution works, but may break if Salesforce change the way they output the HTML for the apex:tab component, so use with caution.

```
<apex:page>
    <li><a href="#">My Tabs</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('{!$Component.tabOne}_lbl').click();">My First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('{!$Component.tabTwo}_lbl').click();">My Second</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="t1" id="tab_pannel">
        <apex:tab label="My First" name="t1" id="tabOne">
        </apex:tab>
        <apex:tab label="My Second" name="t2" id="tabtwo">
        </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
</apex:page>
```

**Server Side AJAX Solution**

The following solution is supported and maintains the currently selected tab in the controller, then uses **apex:outputLink** to update the selected and rerender the tab component only on the page.

```
<apex:page controller="ClientTabController">
    <apex:form >
    <li><a href="#">My Tabs</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <apex:commandLink value="My First" rerender="tab_pannel">
                <apex:param assignTo="{!ActiveTab}" value="t1"/>
            </apex:commandLink>
        </li>
        <li>
            <apex:commandLink value="My Second" rerender="tab_pannel">
                <apex:param assignTo="{!ActiveTab}" value="t2"/>
            </apex:commandLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <apex:tabPanel switchType="server" value="{!ActiveTab}" id="tab_pannel">
        <apex:tab label="My First" name="t1" id="tabOne">
        {!ActiveTab}
        </apex:tab>
        <apex:tab label="My Second" name="t2" id="tabtwo">
        {!ActiveTab}
        </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

This is the controller code

```
public with sharing class ClientTabController 
{
    public String ActiveTab {get;set;}

    public ClientTabController()
    {
        ActiveTab = 't1';
    }
}
```

I put the value of the ActiveTab property in the tab to check all is working fine...

[image]

[image]

Comment: (@Andrew Fawcett:) See sample code in my answer. It actually makes the Salesforce UI (field labels, etc.) look a little better, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're mixing straight HTML and Visualforce in ways they aren't meant to be mixed. Abandon the tabPanel/tab construct and just use jQueryUI with  tags around each of the tab bodies. You can still use regular Visualforce markup within each tag.

```
<apex:page showChat="false" sidebar="true" controller="MyController" >
<apex:stylesheet value="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" />
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" />
<apex:stylesheet value="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css" />


<script>
    j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    j$(function() {
        j$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
</script>
<body>
<apex:form>
<apex:pageMessages id="pageMessages"/>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li id="tabs-element-0"><a href="#tabs-0">{!$Label.StatusTab}</a></li>
        <li id="tabs-element-1"><a href="#tabs-1">{!$Label.SettingsTab}</a></li>
        <li id="tabs-element-2"><a href="#tabs-2">{!$Label.UsersTab}</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-0">
        <apex:pageBlock id="aStatus" mode="maindetail" helpUrl="http://www.google.com" helpTitle="{!$Label.HelpAndTraining}">
        </apex:PageBlock>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <apex:pageBlock id="aSettings" mode="maindetail" helpUrl="http://www.google.com" helpTitle="{!$Label.HelpAndTraining}">
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <apex:pageBlock id="mUsers" mode="maindetail" helpUrl="http://www.google.com" helpTitle="{!$Label.HelpAndTraining}">
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </div>
</div>
</apex:form>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

Sample VF code (per Mr Fawcett's request).

Comment: Sounds like an interesting option David, how about a small example?

Comment: Nice! +1 from me, good alternative!